# Parse multiple XML elements from string, when some of which may be incomplete

Tags: c#, .net, xml, parsing, xmldocument

I'm looking for a convenient want to parse a string that contains XML, but contains multiple elements some of which may be incomplete!  To understand why I'm doing this, just assume the data is coming over a network connection and it may be incomplete at any given time, so it may look something like this:

Here is a single element:

```
"<note id='104'> <stuff> WEEE!</stuff> </note>"
```

Here is what I'm receiving:

```
myString = "<note id='104'> <stuff> WEEE!</stuff>   </note> <note id"
```

Notice that **the second one** (identical to the first) **is cutoff**.  **I want to parse this in a very easy automatic way such that I can read all correct ones and ignore all incomplete ones.**  THe obvious way is to look for the *note* and the matching */note* but that doesn't always work because the line COULD be written like this  and I can't just look for the /> because that could end up matching with something else... This is where it gets complicated, Hence the reason why I'm looking or something automatic to do this for me!

I'd love to be able to call some function that says

```
List<XmlDocument> xmlList = ExtractCompleteXMLDocsFromThisString(myString);
```

In our above case with myString, it would return one xmlDocument and NOT return the 2nd incomplete one.

Update:  THe below code is working, but is not an efficient way of doing it.

```
        for ( int j = 0; j < myString.Length; j++ )
        {
            for ( int i = j; i < myString.Length+1; i++ )
            {
                string subString = string.Empty;
                try
                {
                    subString = myString.Substring(j, i);
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Can't Get SubString with j = " + j + " i = " + i + " myString.length = " + myString.Length);
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                    Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
                }

                try
                {
                    XmlDocument subStringXML = new XmlDocument();
                    subStringXML.LoadXml(subString);
                    Console.WriteLine("Found a good one!");
                    // Extract good one
                    myString = myString.Remove(j, i);
                    Console.WriteLine(subString);
                    i -= subString.Length;
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    //                  Console.WriteLine("Can't parse:" + subString);
                }
            }
        }
```

Update 2:  Tried Split technique, but found a better method, see Update 3.

Update 3:  XmlReader can handle truncated documents!  See code below.  The only addition that needs to be made is simply handling the exceptions.  But it'll parse out the Xml while it's valid, then hit an exception on ones that are not.  This works perfectly for what I'm doing!  Thanks.

```
        XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
        settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment;
        using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(myString), settings))
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("reader.Name = " + reader.Name);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Could you do a split on <note >? That should create a string array containing all of the xml for a note. The only one you should have to worry about is the last one.

Comment: What is the point of parsing an incomplete document? It won't contain a complete set of data. How do you want to proceed with an uncomplete set of data?

Comment: I *think* he's saying he can have 'bad' cases nested around 'good' cases (not necessarily at the end).  I have no idea how you'd ever put yourself in that scenario though

Comment: Correct, I want to ignore the 'bad' cases.  I have an iOS app with an Asynchronous connection that is receiving data.  I'm stress testing it to see what weird cases I'll run into with getting data out of order, cutoff, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made no mention of what you have tried already in your implementation.  I haven't tested this with your example, but XmlReader is somewhat like using a SAX parser and so should be able to handle a truncated document like this.  What I have in mind is something like:

```
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader("..."))
{
   while (reader.Read())
   {
      if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
      {
         ...
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I get the exception, "Multiple document element was detected" on the reader.Read().  I'm trying to figure out how to handle that right now...  I'll let you know how it goes

Comment: You were right on, see the Update 3 above for how to handle truncated documents.